# Jsoup parses a table 3 times?

Tags: java, html, csv, jsoup

I have this weird issue that I'm at my wits end about. Maybe a fresh set of eyes can oint out the problem!

I'm using jSoup to parse a HTML fileThe problem is the set of tables is being outputted to the file 3-4 times, even when being written to a fresh new file. The first time it is outputted as one straight line across the .csv file but every other time it is formatted exactly as I want it to be. But I obviously want it right the first time and have it so that there is olny a first time!

My code:

```
Document doc = new Document(file.toString());
    doc = Jsoup.parse(file, null);

    Elements tables = doc.select("table");

    for (Element table: tables) {
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");
        for (Element row: rows) {
            Elements cells = row.getElementsByTag("td");
            StringBuffer values = new StringBuffer();
            for (Element cell: cells) {
                String cellText = cell.text();
                cellText = cellText.replaceAll(",", "");
                cellText = cellText.replaceAll("£", ",£");
                cellText = cellText.replaceAll(",£", "£");
                System.out.println(cellText);
                values.append(cellText + ",");
            }
            System.out.println(values.toString());
            addToFile(values + ",");
        }
    }

// add new data to mySNMPResults file
private static void addToFile(String myString) { // add newest entry to .csv
                                                    // file
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "MyParsedDOMTree.csv", true));
        out.write(myString + "\n");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It could also just be a case of complex HTML file, various tables nested in each other, but I don't see how that causes tables with number data that only appears once to be output three times...

**EDIT**

Fragment of HTML:

```
<tr bgcolor = "#EEEEEE" height = 20 >
<td width = 15% >
<font face="tahoma" size="1">
Dept '<b>Food Incl Vat</b>'
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£688.95
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£642.60
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£767.95
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£3,007.00
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£1,525.60
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£1,970.40
</td>
<td width = 10% align =
right><font face="tahoma" size="1">
£353.00
</td>
<td width = 1%></td><td width
= 14% align = right bgcolor = "#DFDFDF"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color = '#444444'>
<b>£8,955.50</b></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry had an error in code. Fixed now.

I don't really have enough of your code to make a solid guess, but I'm not sure why you are trying to get the size of the table and then go through that table however many times .size() gets you (I'm guess 3-4). Your going to want to find the root of the tables, then under the roots will be the name of the table (the class name of the tables should be the same), then search each table for whatever you want to find. Maybe some code will help :)

HTML:

```
    <ul class="ListOfTables">
           <li class="TABLE">
                 <span class="item">
           <li class="TABLE">
                 <span class="item">
           <li class="TABLE">
                 <span class="item">
           <li class="TABLE">
                 <span class="item">
```

Java code:

```
public void searchForItems(Document doc)
{
    Elements tables = doc.select("li[class=TABLE]");
    for (Element table : tables)
    {

        String item;
        Elements itemsInTable = table.select("span[class=item]");
        item = itemsIntTable.text();


        //Write the item to file. Depending on what is in your table, you might
        //have to write a more complex scan. Looking for things like attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid the HTML in this case is super complicated compared to the simple one you used. I want to print out every table to the csv file. And the size() method returns the amount of tables on this page (27 in all) so in theory I should just loop through and print out.

Comment: I just noticed if i was to replace size with 5, then the table is printed out exactly once. The problem is I want this to work with several different HTML files with varying sizes so I cant use a fixed number....

Comment: Which is why you need to find all the tables, put them into the Elements array and then scan that array. Can you give me an example of some of the html so I can help you more?

Comment: Also, are you just trying to get the name of the table or are you trying to extract data from each table.

Comment: Literally print out everything in each table (in a clear manner) to a table. For example, the one I'm using as an example is money spent during a week with a total at the end. There are like 20 rows of this. I've updated the code to be simpler as well as what the average table in this file looks like.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the html of what one of these tables looks like? It would really help me narrow down your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33566/discussion-between-collin-and-greengodot)